# In Microsoft Dynamics 365 F&O, how can you Create an Instant Search Filter using Extensions?

Tags: listview, search, filter, extends, dynamics-365-operations

I'm currently trying to work my way through [Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations Development Cookbook - Fourth Edition](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/dynamics-365-for/).  The chapter [Creating a Custom Instant Search Filter](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/dynamics-365-for/9781786468864/90e8e8e3-ad6f-4e38-8f96-504867e5f931.xhtml) demonstrates a custom name filter which *should* update the group list as the user starts typing.

However, this recipe requires the use of overlays, which does not work in the most recent versions of D365 F&O.

How is it possible -- assuming it is possible -- to accomplish the same thing using modern D365 F&O development techniques (e.g. "Extensions")?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, type ahead filtering is not possible with form extensions (at least not with the current extension options). The cookbook recipe states the following:

> We will need to overlay the Vendor group form, as the methods that we will be using for instant search don't yet have an event listener provided by Microsoft.

Specifically, they are talking about the `textChange()` method, which has no event that could be extended.

The only option would be to create a copy of the form instead and replace the standard form with the copy, which you then can customize as you like. Unless it is a must have requirement, I would advise against that, because copying standard objects incurs a technical debt. It may also not be (easily) possible for all forms.

Comment: Cheers for pointing this out, but the book was released August 2017.... I was hoping this was outdated.  I'll leave this question open just in case it is and someone has newer information or a workaround....